# How do I update iMovie to the latest version

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, software-update

I purchased my MacBook Pro in October 2014. It's running OS X 10.10.4 "Yosemite".  Can I update iMovie to the latest version at no charge?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, just go to the Updates pane on the bottom right of the Mac App Store and then click "Update" on the right of iMovie.